# DraggableGridView can't be included in project

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to include [thquinn's `DraggableGridView`](https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView) into my project. I followed all the instructions given there for getting started including [these steps for adding a jar to my project](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29). (`DraggableGridView.jar` is showing as a referenced library.)

It compiles correctly, but when run my project I get the following error in Logcat:

```
I/dalvikvm(798): Could not find method com.animoto.android.views.DraggableGridView.addView, referenced from method com.example.GuessWhat.GuessWhat.loadImages
W/dalvikvm(798): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11: Lcom/animoto/android/views/DraggableGridView;.addView (Landroid/view/View;)V
D/dalvikvm(798): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x003a
E/dalvikvm(798): Could not find class 'com.animoto.android.views.DraggableGridView', referenced from method com.example.GuessWhat.GuessWhat.onCreate
W/dalvikvm(798): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 15 (Lcom/animoto/android/views/DraggableGridView;) in Lcom/example/GuessWhat/GuessWhat;
D/dalvikvm(798): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0023
D/AndroidRuntime(798): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(798): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
E/AndroidRuntime(798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(798): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.GuessWhat/com.example.GuessWhat.GuessWhat}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class com.animoto.android.views.DraggableGridView
E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
```

Here's my import:

```
import com.animoto.android.*;
```

In my activity I have:

```
DraggableGridView dgv = ((DraggableGridView) findViewById(R.id.dgv));
ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
iv.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(Images[index]));
dgv.addView(iv);
```

The last line is where the build error is. What am I missing?

Comment: Does Eclipse see the `com.animoto.android.*` package? Are there any errors in loading that package?

Comment: no, it dosent show any compile errors.... I am even able to invoke the methods inside the package..DraggableGridView dgv;

Comment: It seems that you're trying to reference a method as a class; `addView` is likely a method of the class `DraggableGridView`. Please add a code snippet.

Comment: no, it dosent show any compile errors.... I am even able to invoke the methods inside the package..Here is what i did. import com.animoto.android.*; In my activity I did DraggableGridView dgv;dgv=((DraggableGridView) findViewById(R.id.dgv));ImageView iv=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());iv.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(Images[index]));
      dgv.addView(iv);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as Eclipse can resolve your dependency but Dalvik cannot, it seems that the library wasn't bundled with your application. The typical cause of this is adding your library as a normal Java dependency into `/lib`, whereas building for Android expects the jar in `/libs`. [See also this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132443/library-import-issues)

Secondly, [looking at the source](https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView/blob/master/src/com/animoto/android/views/DraggableGridView.java), it appears that your import is not specified correctly. DraggableGridView's qualified name is `com.animoto.android.views.DraggableGridView`.

Your activity should declare the import as:

```
import com.animoto.android.views.DraggableGridView;
```

Comment: oh, i imported that line, and it still says the same error... here is what i wrote in my xml.. is this rite?   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.animoto.android.views.DraggableGridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dgv" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    
</com.animoto.android.views.DraggableGridView>

Comment: There are no compilation problems in your IDE? Are you running a bare debug version (i.e. not minimizing or obfuscating anything using Proguard)?

Comment: No, there are no compilation problems in eclipse. I dont know much about progaurd. but i can see that a progaurd.cfg file is created in my project. i tried doing this -keep public class com.animoto.android.views.DraggableGridView; and i still get the same error!

Comment: If you're not building through Ant or Maven, then Proguard is not being invoked. Does `DraggableGridView.jar` appear under Android library dependencies in the project's Java build path? It should appear in a similar fashion [as illustrated here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Cuc.png).

Comment: Make sure that you have the jar located under `/libs`, and **not** under `/lib`.

Comment: ok, great.. i got it!!!! it works now... thanks a lot for your help.... :)Basically my jar was not under the android library dependency...

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the comment. Glad it worked out!